# FDQuery and OnCalcFields, get the previous line

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

Delphi 10.3.3
FireDAC: DBGrid / FDQuery / MySQL
VCL

Hi all,

I have a table with these fields

```
----------------------
|  id  |    data      |
----------------------
|  1   | 0=A;1=B;2=C  |
|  2   | 2=Z          |
|  3   |              |
|  4   | 0=Y;1=X      |
|  5   |              |
|  6   |              |
```

Each row of data represents only the change in the table

I would like this to be display in a DBGRID:

```
-----------------------
|  id  | C0 | C1 | C2 |
-----------------------
|  1   | A  | B  | C  |
|  2   | A  | B  | Z  |
|  3   | A  | B  | Z  |
|  4   | Y  | X  | Z  |
|  5   | Y  | X  | Z  |
|  6   | Y  | X  | Z  |
```

What I can do for now is only the following table:

```
-----------------------
|  id  | C0 | C1 | C2 |
-----------------------
|  1   | A  | B  | C  |
|  2   |    |    | Z  |
|  3   |    |    |    |
|  4   | Y  | X  |    |
|  5   |    |    |    |
|  6   |    |    |    |
```

To obtain this result, I create additional columns in the event FDQuery1.BeforeOpen
And in the event OnCreateFields, I fill each column but **I don't know the previous row content**,

So, how can I do to fill in the missing fields in the DBgrid?
Thanks 
Franck

Comment: You could use a `TStringGrid` instead.

Comment: Does first row always contain all states? Do you need to edit or add row?

Comment: Olivier: I've tried with a TStringGrid but it takes more time to update (5 times)

Comment: sddk: First row does not contain always all states. I don't need to edit or add row, just display it.

Comment: What do you mean by "more time to update"? To display the grid? It shouldn't. How many rows do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `OnCalcFields`, rather than `OnCreateFields`.

What you need
is certainly possible, either server-side by deriving the necessary values from the prior
row using e.g. a SQL subquery or client-side using calculated fields. This answer is about doing it
client-side.

The problem with doing client-side calculations involving another dataset row is that
to do this you need to be able to move the dataset cursor during the OnCalcFields event.  However, at the time, the DataSet will be in either dsCalcFields or dsInternalCalc state
and, while it is, you can't easily move to another row in the dataset.  It is *possible* to do this, but
requires declaring a descendant dataset class (TMyFDQuery) so that you can access the `SetTempState`
necessary to do revert to the prior state after you've picked up the necessary info from the "other"
row and, if what you need involves more that one field, you need somewhere to store the values temporarily.
So doing it that way gets messy.

A much cleaner approach involves using functional similarity between FireDAC's datasets and TClientDataSets.
One of the nice features of TClientDatasSets is the ease with which you can move the dataset contents between
two CDSs simply by doing

```
CDS2.Data := CDS1.Data;
```

FireDAC datasets can do the same trick, but between any FD dataset types.  So here is what I would do in your
situation:

1. Add an FDMemTable to your form/datamodule and copy the query data into it in the FDQuery's AfterOpen event like
   this:

```
procedure TForm2.FDQuery1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  FDQuery1.DisableControls;
  try
    FDMemTable1.Data := FDQuery1.Data;
    FDMemTable1.Open;
  finally
    FDQuery1.First;
    FDQuery1.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

The FDQuery1.First is to force it to re-do its calculated fields once the FDMemTable data is available
(during the initial FDQuery1.Open, it can't be, of course).

2. In the FDQuery's OnCalcFields event, use code like this to base the calculated fields'
   values on values picked up from the prior row (if there is one of course, the first
   row can't hae a "prior" row):

```
procedure TForm2.FDQuery1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if FDMemTable1.Active then begin
    if FDMemTable1.Locate('ContactID', FDQuery1.FieldByName('ContactID').AsInteger, []) then begin
      FDMemTable1.Prior;
      if not FDMemTable1.Bof then begin
        //  Set FDQuery1's calculated fields that depend on prior row
        FDQuery1.FieldByName('PriorRowID').AsInteger := FDMemTable1.FieldByName('ContactID').AsInteger;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

In this example, my queried dataset has a `ContactID` primary key and the calculated value is simply the ContactID value from the prior row.  In real life, of course, it
would be more efficient to use persistent field variables rather than keep calling `FieldByName`.

I suppose another possibility might be to use the CloneCursor method to obtain a lookup cursor
to access the "prior" row, but I've not tried that myself and it may not be possible anyway
(what happens about the calculated fields in the CloneCuror copy?).

Comment: Thank you very much for your very complete response. I have done some testing using FDmemTable and this seems to be the solution. I now need to integrate this into my application. Thanks again !

Comment: Glad to help.  Once you've finished intergrating it, it would be great if you could accept this answer (by clicking the tick icon at its LHS).